# What metal(s) are old game console RF shields made of and coated with?

Tags: rf, shielding, metal

I'm restoring my old game consoles (like NES) and am having trouble finding what the RF shields are made out of and coated with so I can sand out the corrosion and re-plate them.

I thought it might be steel sheet metal plated with Zinc and chromate because of the dark corrosion on top and light rust spots over the output section, but have been unable to verify that. Someone suggested that it might be coated in tin, but was unsure.

Comment: Cost was a major factor, probably tin coated steel, since it is cheap. This is what "tin" cans are made of. Could also be zinc, see if there is any evidence of *spangle*. https://tampasteel.com/what-is-galvanized-metal/